# doxygen: how to document the class member function both at class reference and file reference

Tags: c++, class, doxygen

in header file

```
class test{
public:
   void Function();
}
```

and in source file

```
void test::Function(){
 ...
}
```

when i run doxygen for this, the description of the 'Function' is appeared only at class reference

i want to see it at file reference too.

is there any option or another solution?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? I don't think this is possible. One of the problems that will appear is, e.g. when referring to the function in another file (i.e. e.g. calling it or using it in a description), where to jump to: to the class or the file. Note that at the bottom of the HTML page of the class you can get (by default enabled) a list of files from which the documentation is generated.

Comment: @albert thank you for the comment. now i understand the reaseon why file reference can not have the class member function